# Get-Content cannot take data from a file to input in a exe file

Tags: powershell, exe

I have been trying to use Get-Content command in powershell to take inputs into my exe file which is complied from a cpp file, and it worked before, but recently it doesn't work.

```
Get-Content path | ./exe
```

I have tried all the exe files that worked before, and they all don't work all of a sudden, which really confused me.

Edit:
This is a program (test.cpp compile to test.exe) I used for testing:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int test;
    cin >> test;
    cout << "Input is " << test << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and the content in the text file (test.txt) is:

```
10
```

and I used this command in Powershell:

```
Get-Content test.txt | ./test.exe
```

Then the result is:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\C++ codes> Get-Content test.txt | ./test.exe
Input is 0
```

The expected result should be 10 instead of 0

Hex-dump of text file

```
           Path: C:\Users\User\Desktop\C++ codes\test.txt

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   31 30                                            10
```

Comment: If you don't pipe the output to your program, does it work? Do you get the output you expected? Also, run the program itself without the pipe, and input the text or data manually in the terminal, does that work?

Comment: And what *is* `./exe`? Is if a program you have written? What does it do? What changed with the program since it last worked? What changed on your system as a whole since it last worked?

Comment: The program works fine if I input manually, but if I use an .txt file to pipe into my exe file, it does not work.
And I haven't changed the programs. I had few programs to test and they all don't work

Comment: For example I used this `Get-Content testcase/input01.txt | ./pa3`
I'm not sure if my recent Windows update affects this

Comment: If you run only `Get-Content testcase/input01.txt` do you get the expected text displayed? In the fight format that the program `./pa3` expects?

Comment: @KevinOuO What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: Yes, I get the expected text.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the version of PS is 5.1.19041.2673

Comment: Don't ask me why: works if you change `int test;` to `string test;`. Strangely enough, even `echo 10|./test.exe` works from `cmd` (but doesn't work from `PowerShell` 5) with `int test;` !!! Works as explected with `string test;`. 

Comment: Use a hex-editor (or similar) to display the text file. Are there some weird unexpected bytes before the contents?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, the text file is fine

Comment: Would you mind showing the hex-dump as well, please? :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sure I have edited the post, but I'm not sure if it's the hex-dump.

Comment: That's perfect, and indeed show us that the file contents is what it's supposed to be. :) Sorry for nagging about this, but that file together with the code you show should be working fine. So, with the code you show and the file you show, there shouldn't really be a problem. Which means the only possible source of the problem is PowerShell itself. And unfortunately I don't know it well-enough to be able to help you more.